# ¿Cómo cambiar nombre de filas de un data frame a partir de una columna?

Tags: r

Mi data frame es el siguiente

```
  Nombres1      ConcentPS Altura Dim_cop Precip  Temp V_Viento
   <chr>             <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 N_15/03_Sauce    3.25     12.3      12  116      21      5.9
 2 N_15/03_Sauce    1.97      5         6  116      21      5.9
 3 N_15/03_Sauce    2.16      9.5      14  116      21      5.9
 4 N_15/03_Sauce    2.64      8        10  116      21      5.9
 5 N_20/03_Sauce    0.312    12.3      12  116      21      5.9
 6 N_20/03_Sauce    0.0882    5         6  116      21      5.9
 7 N_20/03_Sauce    0.209     9.5      14  116      21      5.9
 8 N_20/03_Sauce    0.383     8        10  116      21      5.9
 9 N_15/04_Sauce    0.333    12.3      12   87.8    21      7.7
10 N_15/04_Sauce    0.343     5         6   87.8    21      7.7
```

Intenté colocar los nombres de las filas con:

```
NewPS <- data.frame(NewPS, row.names = Nombres1)
```

y obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

> Error in data.frame(NewPS, row.names = Nombres1) :    object
>   'Nombres1' not found

Comment: Con respecto a esto, me surje una duda: Cómo elimino la columna duplicada que se genera al asignar los nombres, para efectuar el análisis estadístico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpretando tu código, entiendo que lo que buscas es definir los nombres de las filas, con el valor de la columna `Nombre1`, el problema es que la función `data.frame` espera un simple vector para `rownames` y lo que le estas pasando, es el nombre de una columna pero sin referencia al objeto en sí. La forma correcta sería algo así:

```
NewPS <- data.frame(NewPS, row.names = NewPS$Nombres1)
```

La confusión, puede venir por el lado del uso de funciones de `tidyverse/dplyr` que evalúan los parámetros de una forma no estándar y normalmente pueden recibir directamente los nombres de columna. `data.frame` es una función base que evalúa los parámetros de forma estándar.

De cualquier manera, te recomiendo evitar esta forma de definir los `rownames` ya que por abajo estás haciendo una copia completa del objeto original. Lo óptimo sería hacer:

```
rownames(NewPS) <- NewPS$Nombres1
```

Ahora, resuelto este problema, lo siguiente es que por definición los `rownames` deben ser valores únicos y por el ejemplo que has brindado, no lo son. Con lo cual seguramente tendrás un error del tipo:

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) :    duplicate 'row.names'
>   are not allowed Además: Warning message: non-unique values when
>   setting 'row.names': ‘N_15/03_Sauce’, ‘N_15/04_Sauce’, ‘N_20/03_Sauce’

Revisa tu criterio para construir los nombres de fila, tal vez necesites otra columna, una combinación de más de una o simplemente agregar un numerador:

```
rownames(NewPS) <- paste0(NewPS$Nombres1, "-",1:nrow(NewPS))
```

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente  el comando "rownames(NewPS) <- NewPS$Nombres1¨ muchísimas gracias por su ayuda, ocurrió exactamente lo que me señala, dió error debido a que hay 4 repeticiones con nombres iguales, procedí a colocar nombres diferentes en cada fila y funcionó. Lo último que hice fue eliminar la columna con NewPS$Nombres  <- NULL. Abrazos desde Loja-Ecuador